# After upgrade to play 2.5 : Error injecting constructor

Tags: scala, playframework

I have just updated to Play 2.5.2, and my filter (which runs on Login) gives me the following error :

```
ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: There is no started application
  at filters.LoginFilter.<init>(LoginFilter.scala:15)
```

I had to modify my code a bit to match the new changes set to Filter by the 2.5.2 :

```
import akka.stream.Materializer
import com.google.inject.Inject
import play.api.Play._
import play.api.cache.CacheApi
import play.api.mvc.Results._
import play.api.mvc.{Filter, RequestHeader, Result}

import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class LoginFilter @Inject() (implicit val mat: Materializer, ec: ExecutionContext) extends Filter {
}
```

I had to add the @Inject with Materializer otherwise I was having an error message saying that the class should be abstract or should implement Materializer.

How could I fix this issue ? thanks !

Comment: Something in your code seems to require a running application. Usual suspects are Play.current, Play.configuration and the likes. You might have to show the entire filter class and potentially more of the stacktrace. Also, which lines number 15?

Comment: What is the issue? It seems like using DI fixed it for you?

Comment: I have the same problem, but with `GzipFilter` instead. I'm wondering if the problem is that one of the deprecated `object` controllers (instead of the new ones with `class .. @Inject()....`) results in the filter being created too early, before the app has started. And that converting to `class ... @Inject()` would fix this. — Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

I'm actually not sure about this one and honestly I don't know the difference but in all my files there is the javax.inject not the google inject, so it might be worth a try.

Instead of:

```
import com.google.inject.Inject
```

try:

```
import javax.inject.Inject
```

Comment: Whether you're using Google's annotation or the one from javax shouldn't matter as long as you're sticking with guice. To make your code a bit DI-container independent, you might want to use the javax one though.